# Server-side only Webhook

Tags: mariadb, webhooks, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm quite new to this webhook/not-pooling-requests world, so please lend me a hand here.

My website has a database that is accessed through IIS 8 and its pooling configuration.  I'd like to get rid of this pooling configuration as its consuming a lot of CPU power and set-up a webhook instead.

Just to be clear, this webhook would NOT delete or create any data, just retrieve it from my database and send it to my website, making it "real time" and consuming a lot less processing power in the means of doing so.

Question is, how can I do it?

My setup is as follows:
Website retrieving info from my Windows Server 2012 R2, which retrieves the info through IIS-8 pooling process from my database(MariaDB) in my Linux server.

I appreciate any help whatsoever.

20/05/2018(edit): No one? Really?

Comment: Did you mean "polling" instead of "pooling"?  I don't think webhooks would replace pooling.

Comment: Yes, I did. My mistake. English is not my primary language and I try my best. Sorry for the ignorance.